# Clojure series of defs but don't expose to the outer scope all of them

Tags: clojure

At the head of my clojure file I have a series of defs, some of which are only stepping-stone defs, i.e. are not meant to be used further down the file. I.e.

```
def src-folder (File. "src")
def lib-folder (File. src-folder "lib")
def dist-folder (File. src-folder "bin") 
;; I only care for the lib-folder and dist-folder beyond this point
```

What's the right way to do that in Clojure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `let` instead of `def` for the first throw-away definition, and nest the remaining `def` calls inside the `let`:

```
(let [root-dir (File. "projects/my-project")
      src-folder (File. root-dir "src")]
  (def lib-folder (File. src-folder "lib"))
  (def dist-folder (File. src-folder "bin")))
```

The value of the `src-folder` local binding is discarded after the `let` is evaluated, leaving only the `lib-folder` and `dist-folder` vars accessible to the rest of the program.

Comment: Can you have more than one local, throw-away binding inside the [] of the let form? Perhaps more than one need to be discarded and not necessarily the first one...

Comment: Yes, you can have as many as you like, and they're evaluated in series so later bindings can reference previous ones inside the same `let`. Modified the example to show this.

Answer (score 4):

If they were `defn`s (i.e. functions) you could simply use `defn-` to make a private function.

For `def`s you have to explicitly set them as private:

```
(def ^:private src-folder (File. "src"))
```